# Absolute positioning breaks my css carousel

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm working on a CSS carousel that I will insert into an HTML email. It's basically a form with radio buttons. Every
time a label is clicked for a radio button, it should scroll to the next slide by changing the left margin to a lesser
value. There are tabs at the bottom that should act as the labels.

The problem is, to get the tabs to sit on top of the slides, I had to use absolute instead of relative positioning on
the `.car-thumbnails` class. Now, when I click the first or the last tab repeatedly, the carousel will cycle through
*all* of the tabs.

I inspected the code, and it's like clicking the first or last tab checks and unchecks all of the other radio button
inputs. Why would position:absolute affect it this way?

I know that's a lot of information, but I'm completely at a loss.

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel slide responsive" style="overflow:hidden;display:none;max-height:0px;width:580px;" width="580">
    <input id="car-cbox-support" type="checkbox" checked="" style="display:none!important">
    <input name="car-radio" type="radio" id="car1-radio-1" class="car-radio car-radio1" style="display:none!important">
    <input name="car-radio" type="radio" id="car1-radio-2" class="car-radio car-radio2" style="display:none!important">
    <input name="car-radio" type="radio" id="car1-radio-3" class="car-radio car-radio3" style="display:none!important">
    <input name="car-radio" type="radio" id="car1-radio-4" class="car-radio car-radio4" style="display:none!important">
    <input name="car-radio" type="radio" id="car1-radio-5" class="car-radio car-radio5" style="display:none!important">
    <div class="car-cont" style="position:relative;background-color:#ffffff;">
        <div class="car-frames">
            <!-- Slide 1 Main Image -->
            <a href="#"><img src="/green.png" alt="" border="0"></a>
            <!-- Slide 2 Main Image -->
            <a href="#"><img src="/purple.png" alt="" border="0"></a>
            <!-- Slide 3 Main Image -->
            <a href="#"><img src="/blue.png" alt="" border="0"></a>
            <!-- Slide 4 Main Image -->
            <a href="#"><img src="/red.png" alt="" border="0"></a>
            <!-- Slide 5 Main Image -->
            <a href="#"><img src="/yellow.png" alt="" border="0"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="car-controls">
            <!--When slide 1 (car-nav-1) is showing, clicking the left arrow should transition to slide 5 (car1-radio-5) -->
            <label for="car1-radio-5" class="car-ltn car-nav-1"></label>
            <!--When slide 1 (car-nav-1) is showing, clicking the right arrow should transition to slide 2 (car1-radio-2) -->
            <label for="car1-radio-2" class="car-rtn car-nav-1"></label>
            <!--When slide 2 (car-nav-2) is showing, clicking the left arrow should transition to slide 1 (car1-radio-1) -->
            <label for="car1-radio-1" class="car-ltn car-nav-2"></label>
            <!--When slide 2 (car-nav-2) is showing, clicking the right arrow should transition to slide 3 (car1-radio-3) -->
            <label for="car1-radio-3" class="car-rtn car-nav-2"></label>
            <!--When slide 3 (car-nav-3) is showing, clicking the left arrow should transition to slide 2 (car1-radio-2) -->
            <label for="car1-radio-2" class="car-ltn car-nav-3"></label>
            <!--When slide 3 (car-nav-3) is showing, clicking the right arrow should transition to slide 4 (car1-radio-4) -->
            <label for="car1-radio-4" class="car-rtn car-nav-3"></label>
            <!--When slide 4 (car-nav-4) is showing, clicking the left arrow should transition to slide 3 (car1-radio-3) -->
            <label for="car1-radio-3" class="car-ltn car-nav-4"></label>
            <!--When slide 4 (car-nav-4) is showing, clicking the right arrow should transition to slide 5 (car1-radio-5) -->
            <label for="car1-radio-5" class="car-rtn car-nav-4"></label>
            <!--When slide 5 (car-nav-5) is showing, clicking the left arrow should transition to slide 4 (car1-radio-4) -->
            <label for="car1-radio-4" class="car-ltn car-nav-5"></label>
            <!--When slide 5 (car-nav-5) is showing, clicking the right arrow should transition to slide 1 (car1-radio-1) -->
            <label for="car1-radio-1" class="car-rtn car-nav-5"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="car-thumbnails" style="display:none;">
        <div class="car-container">
            <!-- Thumbnail 1 -->
            <label for="car1-radio-1" class="car-thumb car-thumb-1">
                <p valign="middle"
                    style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:22px;vertical-align:middle;width:100%;height:auto;line-height:40px;color:#ffffff;margin:0px;">
                    green
                </p>
            </label>
            <!-- Thumbnail 2 -->
            <label for="car1-radio-2" class="car-thumb car-thumb-2">
                <p valign="middle"
                    style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:22px;vertical-align:middle;width:100%;height:auto;line-height:40px;color:#ffffff;margin:0px;">
                    purple
                </p>
            </label>
            <!-- Thumbnail 3 -->
            <label for="car1-radio-3" class="car-thumb car-thumb-3">
                <p valign="middle"
                    style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:22px;vertical-align:middle;width:100%;height:auto;line-height:40px;color:#ffffff;margin:0px;">
                    blue
                </p>
            </label>
            <label for="car1-radio-4" class="car-thumb car-thumb-4">
                <p valign="middle"
                    style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:22px;vertical-align:middle;width:100%;height:auto;line-height:40px;color:#ffffff;margin:0px;">
                    red
                </p>
            </label>
            <label for="car1-radio-5" class="car-thumb car-thumb-5">
                <p valign="middle"
                    style="font-family:'Lato', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:22px;vertical-align:middle;width:100%;height:auto;line-height:40px;color:#ffffff;margin:0px;">
                    yellow
                </p>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
    /* bugfix for Android 4.4 to support e ~ y */
    body {
        -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes bugfix {
        from {
            padding: 0;
        }

        to {
            padding: 0;
        }
    }

    /* Hide Fallback content first */
    .fallback {
        display: none;
    }

    .carousel {
        display: block !important;
        max-height: none !important;
        position: relative;
    }

    div[class~="aolmail_carousel"] {
        display: none !important;
    }

    div[class~="aolmail_fallback"] {
        display: block !important;
        max-height: none !important;
        position: relative;
    }

    /*
Selective blocking for clients.
- Samsung (#MessageViewBody) - no absolute positioning
- Comcast/Zimbra (body.MsgBody) - inconsistent CSS support
*/
    #MessageViewBody .fallback,
    body.MsgBody .fallback {
        display: block;
    }

    #MessageViewBody .carousel,
    body.MsgBody .carousel {
        display: none !important;
    }

    input {
        display: none;
    }

    .carousel a {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .carousel .car-frames img {
        display: block !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
    }

    .carousel.responsive {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    .carousel.slide a {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        opacity: 1;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-animation: slide-anim 15s linear infinite;
    }

    .carousel.slide a:nth-child(1) {
        position: relative;
        -webkit-animation-delay: -16s;
    }

    .carousel.slide a:nth-child(2) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: -13s;
    }

    .carousel.slide a:nth-child(3) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: -10s;
    }

    .carousel.slide a:nth-child(4) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: -7s;
    }

    .carousel.slide a:nth-child(5) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: -4s;
    }

    /* iOS doesn't like negative delay with translates (transform:translateX(100%);) */
    /* So we use margin although it is less "smooth" */
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-anim {

        /* start slide in */
        0% {
            margin-left: 100%;
        }

        /* end slide in */
        5% {
            margin-left: 0%;
        }

        /* start slide out */
        20% {
            margin-left: 0%;
        }

        /* end slide out */
        25% {
            margin-left: -100%;
        }

        /* start slide out */
        40% {
            margin-left: -100%;
        }

        /* end slide out */
        45% {
            margin-left: -200%;
        }

        60% {
            margin-left: -200%;
        }

        /* end slide out */
        65% {
            margin-left: -300%;
        }

        80% {
            margin-left: -300%;
        }

        /* end slide out */
        85% {
            margin-left: -400%;
        }

        100% {
            margin-left: -400%;
        }
    }

    .carousel.slide .car-radio:checked~.car-cont .car-frames {
        position: relative;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 500% !important;
        transition: left 1s;
    }

    .carousel.slide .car-radio2:checked~.car-cont .car-frames {
        left: -100%;
    }

    .carousel.slide .car-radio3:checked~.car-cont .car-frames {
        left: -200%;
    }

    .carousel.slide .car-radio4:checked~.car-cont .car-frames {
        left: -300%;
    }

    .carousel.slide .car-radio5:checked~.car-cont .car-frames {
        left: -400%;
    }

    .carousel.slide .car-radio:checked~.car-cont a {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .carousel.slide .car-radio:checked~.car-cont a:nth-child(2) {
        position: absolute;
        left: 20%;
        top: 0px;
    }

    .carousel.slide .car-radio:checked~.car-cont a:nth-child(3) {
        position: absolute;
        left: 40%;
        top: 0px;
    }

    .carousel.slide .car-radio:checked~.car-cont a:nth-child(4) {
        position: absolute;
        left: 60%;
        top: 0px;
    }

    .carousel.slide .car-radio:checked~.car-cont a:nth-child(5) {
        position: absolute;
        left: 80%;
        top: 0px;
    }

    /* Navigation arrows */
    .carousel .car-ltn,
    .carousel .car-rtn {
        z-index: 100;
        display: none;
        width: 10%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: transparent;
        top: 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .car-ltn {
        left: 0px;
    }

    .car-rtn {
        right: 0px;
    }

    .carousel .car-ltn::after {
        content: url(http://media.4at5.net/email_domains/olg/0204/leftArrow.png);
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        margin-top: -8px;
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1.5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4));
    }

    .carousel .car-rtn::after {
        content: url(http://media.4at5.net/email_domains/olg/0204/rightArrow.png);
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        left: 10%;
        margin-top: -8px;
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1.5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4));
    }

    .car-ltn::after {
        border-right: 0px solid #ffffff;
        left: 25%;
    }

    .car-rtn::after {
        border-left: 0px solid #ffffff;
        right: 25%;
    }

    .carousel #car-cbox-support:checked~.car-cont .car-nav-1 {
        display: block;
    }

    .car-radio2:checked~.car-cont .car-controls .car-nav-2,
    .car-radio3:checked~.car-cont .car-controls .car-nav-3,
    .car-radio4:checked~.car-cont .car-controls .car-nav-4,
    .car-radio5:checked~.car-cont .car-controls .car-nav-5 {
        display: block;
    }

    .carousel .car-radio:checked~.car-cont,
    .carousel .car-radio:checked~.car-cont *,
    .carousel .car-radio:checked~.car-thumbnails * {
        -webkit-animation: none;
    }

    /* Thumbnails */
    .car-thumbnails {
        position: absolute !important;
        display: block !important;
        bottom: 0px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .carousel #car-cbox-support:checked~.car-thumbnails .car-container {
        display: block !important;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        /*background-color: #473729;*/
    }

    .carousel .car-thumb {
        width: 19.2%;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 100;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 3px 0px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes focus3-anim {
        0% {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        }

        20% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        40% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        60% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        80% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        100% {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        }
    }

    /* to eliminate use of delay */
    @-webkit-keyframes focus3-anim-2 {
        0% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        20% {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        }

        40% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        60% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        80% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        100% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes focus3-anim-3 {
        0% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        20% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        40% {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        }

        60% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        80% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        100% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes focus3-anim-4 {
        0% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        20% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        40% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        60% {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        }

        80% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        100% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes focus3-anim-5 {
        0% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        20% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        40% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        60% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }

        80% {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        }

        100% {
            background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
        }
    }

    .car-thumb:nth-child(1) {
        -webkit-animation: focus3-anim 15s ease-in infinite;
    }

    .car-thumb:nth-child(2) {
        /*-webkit-animation: focus3-anim 15s linear 5s infinite;*/
        -webkit-animation: focus3-anim-2 15s ease-in infinite;
    }

    .car-thumb:nth-child(3) {
        /*-webkit-animation: focus3-anim 15s linear 10s infinite;*/
        -webkit-animation: focus3-anim-3 15s ease-in infinite;
    }

    .car-thumb:nth-child(4) {
        /*-webkit-animation: focus3-anim 15s linear 10s infinite;*/
        -webkit-animation: focus3-anim-4 15s ease-in infinite;
    }

    .car-thumb:nth-child(5) {
        /*-webkit-animation: focus3-anim 15s linear 10s infinite;*/
        -webkit-animation: focus3-anim-5 15s ease-in infinite;
    }

    .car-radio:checked~.car-thumbnails .car-thumb:nth-child(1),
        {
        background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5) !important;
    }

    .car-radio1:checked~.car-thumbnails .car-thumb:nth-child(1) {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    .car-radio2:checked~.car-thumbnails .car-thumb:nth-child(2),
    .car-radio3:checked~.car-thumbnails .car-thumb:nth-child(3),
    .car-radio4:checked~.car-thumbnails .car-thumb:nth-child(4),
    .car-radio5:checked~.car-thumbnails .car-thumb:nth-child(5) {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
    .carousel .car-thumb {
        width: 19.2%;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 100;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0px 0px;
        background-color: rgba(72, 72, 72, 0.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a working code snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you click your leftmost and rightmost tabs, you're actually clicking the left and right arrows above the tabs (the arrows are set to 100% height).

You can fix this by setting your tabs container's z-index to be greater than that of the arrows:

```
/* Thumbnails */
.car-thumbnails {
  position:absolute !important;
  display:block !important;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 101;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/69gvwzf4/1/

Comment: You are a life saver! It seems so simple, but I would never have figured it out without you. Many thanks!